# Multiple small modules in Maven project

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project which has multiple small utility classes which I want to package as separate jars, e.g. `json-utils`, `xml-utils` etc.

How can I manage this kind of build within a larger project?
Is the only way to do this by declaring each of these classes within a their own separate module? And does each one then need its own subfolder?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with _maven-assembly-plugin_? You're not referring to it in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic concepts of Maven is one project (module), one artifact (`jar`, `war`, etc.):

> [Because a project is defined by a unique set of coordinates consisting of a group identifier, an artifact identifier, and a version [...]](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conceptual.html)

So, "yes" to your last two questions.

Comment: Thanks - was hoping I could save some mess and define multiple small jars together